# Why must I bind this object to its own method?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, scope, this

If I run:

```
var dog = {
    sound: "woof",
    talk: function(){
        console.log(this.sound)
    }
}
document.addEventListener("click",dog.talk)
```

undefined is logged; only when I bind the dog to its function - `document.addEventListener("click",dog.talk.bind(dog))` - does it work.

Why does one need to bind the dog to its method?

Is the function not being called on the dog - like normal - only with the event data being passed as parameters?

Comment: when object call the talk method this will refer to caller object so this will refer to caller object but not dog object.

Comment: you set the click event listener on the global document. this means that on every click (no matter where), you'll  trigger the `dog.talk` function you provided.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? getting the HTML element that the user clicked on?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following read on `this`. http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

Apparently, `this` is only defined at the point that an object invokes a function that uses the keyword `this`. And at that point `this` is defined as the object that called the function. Therefore, in your case `this` would have been bound to, I guess, the document object. In your function then the `this` would be referring to document.sound, which is undefined.

In other words, even though inside your dog object it looks like `this.sound` should refer to the local sound variable, it does not at the time that the function was called.

Answer (score 0):

The `this` in line `console.log(this.sound)` refers to `document` element, not `dog` object.

```js
var dog = {
    sound: "woof",
    talk: function(){
     console.log(this)
        console.log(this.sound)
    }
};

document.addEventListener("click",dog.talk)
```

Snapshot:

[image: 1]

If you want to use `this` inside `dog` object. You can edit the event:

```js
var dog = {
    sound: "woof",
    talk: function(){
        console.log(this)
      console.log(this.sound)
    }
};

document.onclick = function () {
 dog.talk();
};
```